# When testing a static method, the preloadWeek method is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am using `react-universal-component` library and writing a test to run a static method within a React component:

// HOC

```
const detector = Component => {
    const Decision = props => {
        ...
    };

    Decision.fetchData = () => {
        const InnerComponent = Component.preloadWeak();
        return InnerComponent.fetchData();
    };

    return Decision;
};
```

// Jest Test

```
import React from 'react';
import universal from 'react-universal-component';

const PaymentPageComponent = () => <div>Payment Page</div>;
PaymentPageComponent.fetchData = () => "data";

const DynamicComponent = universal(PaymentPageComponent);

test('The fetchData method in the component is executed', () => {
    const Component = detector(DynamicComponent);
    const data = Component.fetchData();
    expect(data).toEqual("data");
});
```

but the test is returning

```
Expected: "data" 
Received: {}
```

When checking the vale of `Component` in `Decision.fetchData` it indeed shows me a UniversalComponent:

```
{ [Function: UniversalComponent]
      contextTypes:
       { store:
          { [Function: bound checkType] isRequired: [Function: bound checkType] },
         report:
          { [Function: bound checkType] isRequired: [Function: bound checkType] } } }
```

When checking `Component.preloadWeak()` it comes back as `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

```js
// ./test.js

import PaymentPageComponent from './paymentPageComponent'
import React from 'react'
import universal from 'react-universal-component'

const detector = UniversalComponent => {

    const Decision = props => <UniversalComponent {...props} />

    Decision.fetchData = () => {
        const InnerUniversalComponent = UniversalComponent.preloadWeak()
        return InnerUniversalComponent.fetchData()
    }

    return Decision
}

test('The fetchData method in the component is executed', () => {

    const DynamicComponent = universal('whatever', { path: '/absolute/path/to/paymentPageComponent' })
    const Component = detector(DynamicComponent)
    const data = Component.fetchData()

    expect(data).toEqual('data')
})
```

```js
// /absolute/path/to/paymentPageComponent.js

import React from 'react'

const Payment = () => <div>Payment Page</div>

Payment.fetchData = () => 'data'

export default Payment
```

**Note 1:**

The above solution could have been written in several different ways, but for your purpose, ie. call server side a static method of a universal component, which is what `Universal.preloadWeak` is supposed to be used for, I think it's the most straightforward. The require call is synchronous (as in the server) and it doesn't require the `babel-plugin-universal-component`.

**Note 2:**

I believe that the path in `universal(load, { path })` should be absolute instead of relative, ie. `./path/to/paymentPageComponent'`, because of how Jest is mocking `module.require()`.

**Note 3:**

You were using `universal(PaymentPageComponent)` when it should be:

```js
const UniversalComponent = universal(() => Promise.resolve(PaymentPageComponent), { path: './path/to/paymentPageComponent' })
```

Which is a shortcut for simulating how `babel-plugin-universal-component` is transforming the `universal` call:

```js
universal(import('./path/to/paymentPageComponent'))
// transformed to: 
// universal({ load: () => import('./path/to/PaymentPageComponent'), path: './path/to/PaymentPageComponent' })

export default UniversalComponent
```

**Context:**

`UniversalComponent.preloadWeak` [requires](https://github.com/faceyspacey/react-universal-component/blob/84dc256294b101fd7a336e3d1ea952c3b904baa0/src/index.js#L100) (import) [your](https://github.com/faceyspacey/react-universal-component/blob/84dc256294b101fd7a336e3d1ea952c3b904baa0/src/requireUniversalModule.js#L51) [component](https://github.com/faceyspacey/react-universal-component/blob/84dc256294b101fd7a336e3d1ea952c3b904baa0/src/utils.js#L34) [module](https://github.com/faceyspacey/react-universal-component/blob/84dc256294b101fd7a336e3d1ea952c3b904baa0/src/requireById/index.js), either using `module.require` with `UniversalOptions.path` (server application transpiled with Babel) or using `__webpack_require__` (server or client application compiled with Webpack) with `UniversalOptions.resolve`. These options should be provided either manually or using `babel-plugin-universal-import`.

Comment: Would you mind providing some further context, for example, where to put this and why this should make a difference?

Comment: Edited. I think the `react-universal` documentation is missing some details about this.

Comment: Thanks for adding some more details. I believe that I am using `babel-plugin-universal-import` already - `const universalImportPlugin =
        env === 'development' ? ['universal-import', { babelServer: true }] : 'universal-import';`, so I assume that this should already e working (?)

Comment: Sorry to notice the following a bit late, but you are using `universal(Component)` when it should be `universal(import('./componentPath')`, which is equivalent to `universal(Promise.resolve(Component), { path: './componentPath.js' })` in your test, in which `universal(...)` is not transformed by the plugin.

Comment: Yeah, I tried using import first of all, but that didn't work. I see though that the answers haven't changed, so still the test is returning `Expected: "data" 
Received: {}` - any ideas what to do?

Comment: Edited and live tested the new edited solution. Let me know if it works for you. :)

Comment: Amazing - thank you - the absolute path worked! Really appreciate the time you put in to answer this :)